# Cannot access ControllerBase.ValueProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have been playing around with the [XamlAsyncController](http://xamlaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/), which is based on ASP.NET MVC 2, and tried upgrading it to MVC 3. However, although the original application works OK, if I try to run it in MVC 3, I get a NullReferenceException when attempting to access ValueProvider.

I've tried explicitly loading the default value providers in the Application_Start:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new RouteDataValueProviderFactory());
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new FormValueProviderFactory());
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory());
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new QueryStringValueProviderFactory());

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BootstrapContainer();
    }
```

I'm using Castle Windsor 3 to manage IoC. Does anyone have any idea why the ControllerBase.ValueProvider would be null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up and tried a [different project](http://mvcxaml.codeplex.com/) (a view engine that renders XAML as PNGs).